# Single Page Application (SPA) vs Full Stack Applications. Constraints and Advantages.

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jboss, single-page-application

Currently I am in the process of upgrading our web application from a traditional Spring MVC web application to a single page app with REST endpoints. Our current front-end MVC application does not use REST calls to communicate with the backend, but rather communicates with the backend (written in JAVA) by calling the necessary facades directly. Both JAR files and WAR files are being packaged in a single ear file, and deployed on our production server (currently using JBoss EAP 6).

Since we are now shifting to a single page application, and upgrading our system with a new set of APIs, I am questioning, should the Single Page Application, and the rest of the backend written in JAVA, be hosted on the same server (JBoss EAP 6)? Or should they be split onto separate servers, one to serve the SPA content and one to run the backend? In the latter case, which production server is most appropriate to host the content of the Single Page Application (JS,HTML,and CSS)? ( our backend will still be hosted on JBoss EAP 6 )

Also what are the advantages of separating the front end and backend on different servers?

I tried to search for best practices for deploying Single Page Applications with a JAVA REST endpoint but I haven't found any helpful articles applicable for our needs.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first query:

- Yes you can absolutely separate them,  and ideally you should so you can deploy the front end without dependency on web-service back-end.
- You can deploy your SPA static files with any of the popular web servers like Apache, Nginx, or even on cloud hosting like S3 (behind cloud front CDN).
- Assuming your REST endpoints are still going to be in Java, those would need to reside in Java application server like jBOSS, tomcat or glass fish.

**Constraints/Gotchas :**

1. **Cross domain:**

   - You can either put your JBOSS behind same Apache/Nginx reverse proxy that runs your static files.
   - Or you can enable CORS on web services if your domains are separate.
   - Lastly, jsonp is always an option if your web-services are JSON.
2. **Authentication and Security:**

   - Typically when you go with a full stack web framework like Spring you get a lot of security and authentication out of box. You can protect your site using sessions and CSRF etc. However with REST you typically have to use Token based authentication for your front end to speak with REST services. This is not necessarily difficult, but a different approach, and is hence listed under constraints.

**Advantages:**

1. Easier to scale the back end and front-end separately, with static SPA on a service like amazon S3 and CloudFront CDN you can infinite scaling on that part.
2. The back-end web services can now be easily put behind a load balancer-cluster model because your services are REST.
3. Its way easier to take care of deployments now because of separation of concerns.
4. Lesser regression issues when pushing just front-end changes. You don't have to replace entire WAR file any more.

**Separate Servers or not**

Depends on what kind of traffic your application is expected to handle. Let me lay down three scenarios.

1. **Low traffic**: You can put it one server with Java App server behind that Web server's reverse proxy. The web server will also serve the SPA some directory.
2. **Moderate traffic**: You should separate the fronted and Web Server on one web server and have REST services hosted on Separate machine. Technically this setup won't be much different from option 1, but your App Server will not compete with Web server for CPU cycles to respond to requests.
3. **High traffic**: Same as option 2, but now you can have multiple App servers and SPA Web servers and have one Apache/Nginx to load balance on the top.
4. **Insane traffic over wide geographic region**: You don't want to host those SAP your self in this case. It would be better to go with a a service like Amazon S3 behind CloudFront CDN, so your static content is replicated across the world for optimal response times. This would also reduce that load on your servers.  Now about the App server for hosting the REST endpoints. You can either go with your own servers in cloud that host your cluster or go with PAAS like Heroku or amazon to host your WAR files and scale on demand.

Note: these scaling scenarios don't account for database, as you would need more information about your database to figure how to scale it in the above scenarios.

Hope that helps, please let me know if you need more specifics on any of the things mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of taste.

My self prefer creating a SPA using a generator like [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and then create a service with either Spring IO own setup for webservices (example here: [spring webservice example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)) or Jersey [here](https://jersey.java.net/).

When it comes to deployment are there multiple setups.

Apache | Nginx | S3. Here is a great article for deploying an AngularJS application: [deploying angular app](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/three-easy-ways-deploy-angular-app-free-david-meza)

You will probably still need to use Tomcat, Glashfish or JBOSS ect when it comes to the Java part.

**This is not an answer only my taste of choice**

Answer (score 0):

Now a days, front-end is hosted mostly on separate servers and back-end services on cloud like AWS, In your scenario you can use [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com) for front-end (Html, CSS, JS, Angular) and sure you can use separate server for back-end services, it is also feasible to use Spring MVC as your current framework with it as a restful services.

Take a look at this [demo](https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/angularjs-http-service-ajax-post-code-example)